# Multidimensional List get Position of a String Python

Tags: python, string, list, indexing, set

I got following List

```
relational_scheme = [["F",["DC"]],["A",["EBD"]],["DC" , ["BAF"]],["E",["DB"]]]
```

Now i want to get the second List as a Set like

```
def returnSetOfList(relational_scheme,"F")
```

So that this output generates

```
set(["DC"])
```

How can i make this? an easy Index don't work.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

got it, was just blind 
Solution:

```
def returnSetOfList(scheme,string):
    for x in scheme:
        if string in x:
            return set(x[1])
```

Comment: `[[i,set(j)] for (i,j) in relational_scheme]`

Comment: what is the second list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary and then return the `set()` of the value for a given key.

**Example**

```
>>> def returnSetOfList(scheme, key):
...     a_dict = dict(scheme)
...     return set( a_dict[key] )
... 

>>> relational_scheme = [["F",["DC"]],["A",["EBD"]],["DC" , ["BAF"]],["E",["DB"]]]
>>> returnSetOfList(relational_scheme, "F")
set(['DC'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict comprehension to create a dict and simply get the expected result with indexing:

```
>>> relational_scheme = [["F",["DC"]],["A",["EBD"]],["DC" , ["BAF"]],["E",["DB"]]]
>>> 
>>> d={i:set(j) for i,j in relational_scheme}
>>> d['F']
set(['DC'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the method as:

```
def returnSetOfList(scheme, string):
    for i in scheme:
        if i[0] == string:
            return set(i[1])
```